# C# Discover Implicit Type of variable declared with the var keyword

Tags: c#, visual-studio, var

Say I have the following code:

```
var longValue = 2147483650; // Three more than the max int size
var intValue = 10;
var variableOfUnknownType = longValue - intValue;
```

I want to know what type `variableOfUnkownType` is. (i.e. Is `variableOfUnknownType.GetType() == System.Int64` or `variableOfUnkownType.GetType() == System.Int32`?)

Of course, I could go and carefully read C# documentation on type casting in arithmetic or add a `Console.WriteLine(variableOfUnknownType.GetType());` statement to my code to learn the answer to this question.  However, as per [C#'s var documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx)

> The var keyword instructs the compiler to infer the type of the variable from the expression on the right side of the initialization statement.

which would imply that MS Visual Studio should be able to tell me the type of the variable prior to compiling the code.

My question is:
How can I use MS Visual Studio to tell me the value of this particular `var` variable?

Comment: Simply hover over the 'var' keyword, it will tell you what type is inferred

Comment: That is correct.  My intuition was to hover over the variable name which didn't produce the expected result.

Comment: @JacobHorbulyk What does it show, and how does it conflict with the other options you mentioned?

Comment: Hovering over the ``var`` keyword produces ``System.Int64`` which matches what happens if you call ``Console.WriteLine(variableOfUnknownType.GetType());``  Hovering over the variable name highlights uses of that variable but provides no information on the type of that variable.

Comment: [David Sherret](http://stackoverflow.com/users/188246/david-sherret) That's not what I got with MS VS 2013 and .Net 4.5

Comment: @DavidSherret you are supposed to hover over the var of `var variableOfUnknownType`

Comment: @TimFreese i just realized that after re-reading the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply hover over the 'var' keyword, it will tell you what type is inferred

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr; Answer
Hover over the "var" and you see the type (Hint it is Int64/long)

Long answer:
Just taking your code and replace it with the types that var represents, you get the following code:

```
uint longValue = 2147483650; // Three more than the max int size
int intValue = 10;
long variableOfUnknownType = longValue - intValue;
```

as you can see, those are three different types, but why? uint makes sense. There is no need to occupy 64 bit, if you could do the same with 32 bit and since this is a positive number we can use an unsigned integer.
The int is self explanatory, however the long is a bit confusing at first.

We as programmers know that an `int.MaxValue + 3 - 10` again fits in an `int`, but the compiler does not know that. After all, how does he know that `intVariable` is 10? Simple: He does not. Therefore he infers the type he knows can handle the value. Since we are subtracting here, it could lead to negative values, so he takes the signed type, which can fit the values, which is Int64/long

Btw: This was out of my head. I'd have to check integer arithmetic in c# again to completely verify this.